# Node Executing Twice

Tags: node.js

I have the following simple program in node:

```
http = require("http");
fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     console.log("hello world");
     res.writeHead(200, "{Content-Type:text/html}");
     res.write("<h1>Welcome</h1><p>Paragraph text</p>");
     res.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

I expect to see "hello world" outputted to the terminal once, but I see the message twice. Why is this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are you accessing the server from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser first makes a regular request and then asks for the `favicon.ico`.

To correct this, inspect what comes as the `req.url` and if it's the second request for the favicon, do whatever else you want (including returning 404).

Answer (score 0):

When a browser visits a page, it will make an additional request for the favicon. This is why you're seeing two requests which results in two "Hello World" output.

You can make the modifications here to have the server check for favicon requests before outputting "Hello World".

```
http = require("http");
fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
         res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
         res.end();
     }
     else {
         console.log("hello world");
         res.writeHead(200, "{Content-Type:text/html}");
         res.write("<h1>Welcome</h1><p>Paragraph text</p>");
         res.end();
     }
}).listen(8000);
```